# Macro to replace/encapsulate text in PhpStorm/IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

For example I have the text `login` and I want to wrap in in a function call like `{{ __('login') }}` by just selecting the text and hitting a key combination to perform the change for me, speeding up my work flow.

Is there a way of doing this with PhpStorm/IntelliJ?

Comment: Sure, use Live Templates of the surround kind. Live Templates in general: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html

Comment: Peter could you please approve the answer if it is solved on your side, it may help someone in the future. Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @LazyOne for providing info; i want to expand according to your question.

your template text will be as following if you want to surround texts like `login`;

> `{{ __('$SELECTION$') }}$END$`

or if you want surround texts like `'login'`

> `{{ __($SELECTION$) }}$END$`

After you finalize your live template by selecting `applicable context`, it will be ready to use. When you type and select `login`, then hit `cmd` + `alt` + `j` it will surround.

Another option would be creating a live template which will print everything in the template but you fill `login`.

> `{{ __('$NAME$') }}$END$`

Comment: I tried this but I can't seem to make this work. I don't seem to get how to add the template though I'm sure sure what you're saying it right

Comment: @PeterFox Here are two screenshots about how to do it; https://prnt.sc/skn38j https://prnt.sc/skn487 pressing enter - it will print `{{ __('login') }}`

Comment: ok, I have it working in PHP files now thank you. I'm trying to add it to a .blade.php file though which is what's screwing me up. I have a Blade template type with 'live templates enabled' but doesn't seem to allow me to add to it

Comment: never mind, working now, I needed to add it to the HTML rather than PHP. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @PeterFox if you want you may allow it everywhere https://prnt.sc/sknlw1